# Does every distribution family have a set of maximum entropy constraints?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, maximum-entropy, constraint

I am reflecting on these [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Examples) of maximum entropy distributions. I am (pleasantly) surprised that various common distribution families have maximum entropy constraints.

It got me wondering if having maximum entropy constraints is something that all distribution families have, or if it is something that only some special families of distributions have.

That is, given any family of distributions with support $\mathcal{F}$, will there be some set of maximum entropy constraints? I don't mean whether you can actually derive the constraints, just whether they're guaranteed to exist.

Comment: I suspect this question might be predicated on some confusion between a *distribution* and a *distribution family.*  Every distribution $F$ with finite entropy trivially maximizes the entropy over a collection of distributions: namely, $\{F\}$ itself.  Moreover, unless $F$ is a local minimum of entropy over *all* distributions, there will be a family of neighboring distributions for which $F$ maximizes the entropy.  There's not much content or insight to that statement because you could replace "entropy" by any continuous function of the space of all distributions and it would still be true.

Comment: hi, i'm John, I'll be your mathematical pedant this evening. We need to work on your precise definition of constraints, because of course every distribution is the maximum entropy distribution subject to the constraint of having a particular characteristic function, namely that of the distribution in question.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you've identified an equivocation on my part. It is due more to being careless than confusion. I see what you are saying about individual distributions, as well as singleton sets of distributions.

Comment: @JohnMadden Right, without further constraints on what we'll allow for maximum entropy constraints we get something rather unsatisfying. I think for what I was looking for, you and whuber have shown that the hypothesis is true in a rather uninteresting way.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't even realize I totally duplicated whuber's response haha. Anyways I wouldn't give up so easily, Galen. What if we restrict our attention to moment constraints? Does it work for the distributions you have already seen defined as constrained entropy maxima?

Comment: An informal and not rigoourous answer is that maximum entropy distributions à la Jaynes end up being special cases of exponential families, hence excluding non exponential families.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relation with the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Examples),

> Suppose $S$ is a closed subset of the real numbers $\mathbb {R}$ and
> we choose to specify $n$ measurable functions ${\displaystyle
>   f_{1},\cdots ,f_{n}}$ and $n$ numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$. We consider
> the class $C$ of all real-valued random variables which are supported
> on $S$ (i.e. whose density function is zero outside of $S$) and which
> satisfy the $n$ moment conditions: $${\displaystyle \mathbb {E}
>   [f_{j}(X)]\geq a_{j}\quad {\mbox{ for }}j=1,\ldots ,n}$$ If there is a
> member in $C$ whose density function is positive everywhere in $S$,
> and if there exists a maximal entropy distribution for $C$, then its
> probability density ${\displaystyle p(x)}$ has the following form:
> $${\displaystyle p(x)=\exp \left(\sum _{j=0}^{n}\lambda
>   _{j}f_{j}(x)\right)\quad {\mbox{ for all }}x\in S}\tag{1}$$ where we assume that ${\displaystyle f_{0}(x)=1}$. The constant $\lambda _{0}$ and the
> $n$ Lagrange multipliers ${\displaystyle {\boldsymbol {\lambda
>   }}=(\lambda _{1},\ldots ,\lambda _{n})}$ solve the constrained
> optimization problem with $a_{0}=1$ (this condition ensures that $p$
> integrates to unity): $${\displaystyle \max _{\lambda
>   _{0};{\boldsymbol {\lambda }}}\left\{\sum _{j=0}^{n}\lambda _{j}a_{j}-\int \exp \left(\sum _{j=0}^{n}\lambda _{j}f_{j}(x)\right)dx\right\}\quad \mathrm {subject\;to:\;\;} {\boldsymbol {\lambda }}\geq \mathbf {0} }$$
>
> Using the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions, it can be shown that the
> optimization problem has a unique solution because the objective
> function in the optimization is concave in $\boldsymbol\lambda$.

one can see that the collection of distributions (1) defines an exponential family when $\boldsymbol \lambda$ varies since they write
$${\displaystyle p(x)=c(\boldsymbol{\lambda})h(x)\exp\left(\sum
  _{j=1}^nf_{j}(x)\right)\quad {\mbox{ for all }}x\in S}\tag{2}$$
wrt the Lebesgue measure on $S$.

With this interpretation of the question, one cannot recover every parameterized family of distributions (as, e.g., the Cauchy distributions)

Comment: While the Cauchy family is not an exponential family, it is maximum entropy under a simple constraint https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325143

Comment: @fritzo: As I mentioned in my answer to the linked question, I feel that the constraint does not naturally fit within the maximum entropy context because it is not of the form$$\mathbb E[T(X)]=t_0$$with $T(\cdot)$ being a fixed transform, rather than depending on the parameter.